# Number of segments that cover a point

Tags: algorithm, indexing, data-structures

I'm designing a web service that calculates the number of online users of an arbitrary system.

The input data is the array of tuples (user_id, log_in_time, log_out_time). The service should index this data somehow and prepare data structures in order to efficiently answer the requests of the form: "How many users were online at every time point in (start_time, end_time)?". The response of the service is an array -- number of online users for each time point in the requested interval.

Complication: each user has a set of characteristics (i.e. age, gender, city). Is it possible to efficiently answer the request of the form: "How many users with age=x, city=y, gender=z were online at every time point in (start_time, end_time)?"

The time is an integer (timestamp).

Comment: Are you looking for an in-memory data structure or do you need paging to disk?

Comment: It can be both. If there would be too much indexes, then storing some parts of them on disk is OK

Comment: Clarification: When you say "every" do you mean you only want users who were online for the entire duration of (start_time, end_time) or do you mean overlap during any portion of that time? You can implement either of these, but the exact criteria is a little different.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't formulate the problem properly. I mean, that for every time point in the range the service returns the number of online users at that point of time. For instance, if the range in the request is [100, 150), the response will contain 50 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to answer this question fully because clearly it is a homework assignment, but you didn't declare it as such.

Assuming the time windows are small or the number of simultaneous online users within that window is small, simply solve the first problem, then filter by your demographic criteria.

If the number of simultaneous online users is large and filtering after the fact is too time consuming, then use something similar to a [`boost::multi_index`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to filter on the most sparse dimension first, then do your time range query.

Additionally, most relational databases will do these types of queries out of the box, so the simplest solution would be to store your data in a database with proper indexes and then create the very straightforward query.

Since your comment said that you didn't understand how to use a [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) to do a range query, I'll explain it in my answer. You use a B-tree to look up the minimum of your time range query. The way a B-tree is structured is that successive leaves are adjacent to one another. You first do a logarithmic lookup on the minimum range query bound. This finds you the first point within that time range. Then, you do a linear scan from the starting point to the point where you exceed your maximum bound for your range query.

This means using a B-tree makes your query `O(log(number_of_online_users) + length_of_time_interval)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please be assured that this is not my homework. It's a part of more complicated problem I'm solving.

Comment: I've had similar idea, but looks like it requires storing a list of online users for each time point in order to filter them by demographics? This would be too memory consuming. Also, this approach will require O(number_of_online_users * length_of_time_interval) time to calculate the result. I'm trying to think of smth more efficient

Comment: @Alex I think the suggestion to let a relational database manager handle the queries for you is a good one, but if you really want to code something yourself, an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) will find intervals that overlap a given point or interval in `O(log n)` time rather than `O(n)` over `n` intervals.

Comment: Even just a simple [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) can be used to do range queries in logarithmic time.

Comment: These approaches (interval tree and B-tree) are efficient when the request is to find a number of online users for one single time point. But when the request contains time interval (3600 points for instance) this becomes not that obvious how to scale.

Comment: @Alex "[...] will find intervals that overlap a given point [or interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#With_an_Interval) in `O(log n)`"